# .htaccess Rewrite 505 Error Loop

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to rewrite:

mydomain.com/category.php?id=cat

to

mydomain.com/cat

I have used the following .htaccess code but it keeps showing a 505 error:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /category.php?id=$1 [L]
```

I read on another page that it is because the page keeps looping, but I can't work out how I can fix the code.

Comment: `505 HTTP Version Not Supported`
The server does not support the HTTP protocol version used in the request.

Answer (score 1):

Keep your rule like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /category.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/ category.php?id=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Samething. Nothing is happening.

Comment: Check mod_rewrite has been installed or not using php info. If it so it will work.
Also make sure you don't have any folder with the value of id

Comment: Still not working. When I go to the page, the URL shows as it is, not the rewritten version.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `RewriteCond` to avoice rewrite for `category.php`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEUST_URI} !^ /category.php/(.*)
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/ category.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok this should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/category.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ category.php?id=$1 [R=301,L]
```

Demo: http://ht6.valhook.com/cat

Comment: @Flare Hocke Just edited my answer, now it should work. Note that you need to add the full URL and/or R=301 flag to make the rewrite rule appear in the URL and be explicit otherwise it will remain implicit

Comment: Ok hold on, looks like my testing software is wrong. I will live test it to be sure it 100% works and I will come back to you. Please excuse me.