# 500 Error when '/' in url with url rewriting

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have this .htacess on my server to redirect example/test -> example/test.php.

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://example.net/404

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L]
```

It works for basic url but when I request "example/fakefolder/test" it return a 500 error.

And i have nothing in the logs saying i have a 500 error.

Comment: may be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24994897/htaccess-rewrite-505-error-loop

Comment: That's not the same problem :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're seeing is that the `-f` check when paired with `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` is sort of a "fuzzy" check. It includes pathinfo style matching, which means if you have a file `/script.php` and the request is `/script/blahblah`, the condition `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f` actually **returns true** because it fuzzy matches: `/script.php/blahblah`, which exists as a file, via pathinfo style URL.

You need to be explicit about your path and include the possible `/`.

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://rafflehaven.net/404

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```